# I have requirement where ImposedTerm name needs to be date managed.Could this be done via product designer?

Tags: guidewire, gosu

My imposed term name should be ABC before July 1 and from July 1 it should be XYZ. Is that possible via product designer, if not how it can be done through another possibility ?

I'm thinking another imposed term can be created with the new name and different availability dates but I'm assuming system will confuse as we will be having 2 imposed terms with the same code but with different name and availability dates?

Can someone provide their thoughts on how to implement it ?

Comment: What do you mean by an "imposed term"? This is not a widely known convention in the industry that many people would be familiar with so I request you to provide more details if this is a carrier-specific requirement. Are you trying to refer to a "condition" or something else? Also, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for details on asking questions with clarity.

Comment: yes it refers to conditions under Line of Business

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is my first time posting the question here :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are referring to a product model condition by "imposed term", it is much safer to define 2 different conditions in your scenario. If you intend to make any product model pattern (coverage /exclusion/ condition etc.) available by use of the `StartEffectiveDate` and `EndEffectiveDate` columns in the availability lookup table and have a continuous overlap with another pattern that becomes available after the first one becomes unavailable, it's recommended to define 2 separate patterns.

```
Condition ABC -> StartEffectiveDate = 1st Jan, EndEffectiveDate = 30 Jun
Condition XYZ -> StartEffectiveDate = 1st Jul, EndEffectiveDate = XXX
```

Using the above values in the availability lookup table, Condition XYZ can be made available starting 1st Jul for any jobs that have a reference date on or after 1st Jul (reference date could either be the effective date or edit effective date and there is a whole plugin just to calculate reference date). In this case, each defined condition will have a unique `CodeIdentifier`. It is not possible for 2 product model patterns to have the same `CodeIdentifier` as inquired in the question.

If you intend to change the name of a coverage or condition mid-term, that is neither technically possible nor legally advisable. The ideal way is to initiate a mid-term policy change that will automatically remove the first coverage and add the second coverage when the policy change job is quoted (based on their availabilities). However, I do not think any insurance company would attempt to do that, and a much cleaner way to replace older coverages with newer ones would be to do bulk policy changes as policies quoted on 30th Jun in the above example will continue to offer that coverage until their expiry. Another way would be to stop offering the older coverage to new submissions after a certain date and let older policies get rid of it at renewal.

Comment: the policies which are created before july 1st 2024 should fetch ABC as condition , and after july 1st 2024 it should fetch XYZ as condition. They don't want any change to happen for the existing policies that are already available in the system which are created before jul1st 2024.

Comment: If you are referring to new policies that will be effective/quoted before or after July 1st, 2024 then the availability lookup table-based solution should work and I do not see any issues. Just configure 2 conditions with sequential effective / end dates as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen customers construct a "coverage display name" utility to add to or change the clause name for display purposes.  You could do something like this to meet your need and retain a single clause (and clause code).

But this is a complex piece of coding since you have to consider performance overhead as well as intercept every location where a clause display name may occur including downstream mappings like document production.

Other than that the "2 clause" approach is the only viable solution given the constraints of product model elements.